# Left join, return all columns from first table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Right now, for LEFT JOIN I use "Include":

```
var items = (from item in Content.Entity1.Include("Entity2")
            select new { Value1 = item.Col1, Value2 = item.Col1, ...., Value3 = item.TheReference.Col1});
```

There is a problem with that when there are many columns in first entity that I have to type in.

Is there a possibility to return ALL columns from first entity and specific column for second entity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just return the left entity as a separate one and add additional ones that you wish:

```
from item in Content.Entity1.Include("Entity2")
select new { Left = item, Right = item.TheReference.Col1 };
```

### Using T4

If your code is generic and is repeated entity-by-entity, then I suppose you could write a T4 template that would generate those LINQs for you. But that would mean that those custom *right* entity columns should be provided somehow via template variable.

So. Create a `ttinclude` file and then **N** `tt` files where you set additional variable values and reference the `ttinclude` generator template.

But other than these two (and yours with manual column write) there's nothing else really.

Comment: yeah, this will contain all the columns inside another property but it's not good for my latter implementation...

Comment: @jullin: So you can either change your implementation or type all columns manually because this is correct solution.

Comment: @jullin: It's either you write all your columns manually or return your entity. There's no direct way that you could use to avoid manual columns. But there's an additional edit in my answer.